# Restricting C drive access on windows by limited User but allow to install new software

Tags: windows, privacy

I want to restrict the user to access C drive but want to allow installation of new software. scenario is user is downloading a software and installing from a wizard but he can access to installation directory and get that software executable.which i want to restrict.

Comment: The user could be allowed to save the download file to some other location instead of restricted drive?

Comment: So you want a user to be able to install software but not run it?

Answer (score 4):

The act of installing a program should be reserved for administrators. Normal users should not be allowed to perform these tasks because it opens the possibility for malware to be installed.

If you trust one specific user with such a risky task, then restricting access to the executable file is not your biggest concern, but otherwise the security model should focus on separation of duties.

If you are distributing a program that you wrote and are concerned about piracy I want to point you to this question in programmers SE ["How do you prevent the piracy of your software"](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10340/how-do-you-prevent-the-piracy-of-your-software). In general copy protection has never really worked and other models have proven safer (SaaS for example).